# How to setup an implicit assignment of a class's property?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, operators, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have a custom class and would like to assign a value to one of its properties implicitly. I know Microsoft used to have this built-in to some of the controls, such as `TextBox1 = "Sets the TextBox1.Text property"`. Is that locked down to Microsoft because it was built-in to the compiler or is that available?

This seems similar to an implicit conversion but I need an instance of the result to modify.

My actual code example:

```
public class CustomObject<TObject>
{
    public TObject BaseObject { get; set; }

    //Psuedocode for what I want, this doesn't compile for multiple reason
    public implicit operator CustomObject<TObject>(TObject FillIn)
    {
         this.BaseObject = FillIn;
    }
}

//Usage
var x = new CustomObject<int>();
x = 3; //this is the end result I want to code.
```

Comment: Um, no - you can't set a text box to be a string. If you really, really believe you can, please show that code... because it's not going to work.

Comment: These were called *default properties* and were available in VB.

Comment: Jon, see @slugster 's comment, I was a VB convert. Are *default properties* available in C# for custom classes?

Comment: That's not even remotely possible in C#, since there's no way to override the assignment operator operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `implicit` overload operator in C# cannot **set** a property on an object, it can only **convert** itself to an object.

Default properties from VB6 aren't available in C# or [VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7bfkxc1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: **Visual Basic Note** In previous versions of Visual Basic, you were allowed to implement parameterless default properties. This is no longer allowed. For details, see [Default Property Changes in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7bfkxc1(v=vs.71).aspx) -- [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b6akew6(v=vs.71).aspx)